# Searching through a dictionary and replacing given text with key and value

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary, matching

So I have been trying so many things for a long time and can't seem to get this working:

The basic intended logic of this code is:

- To get the text

  - for each word that matches the regex find the corresponding key in the dictionary
  - replace the match found within the text with the key and value
  - once all the matches are found and replaced within the text then exit out the loop and return the newly edited text

This is my method to do that right now:

```
public string TextSpeak(string text)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"H:\SECourseowork\textwords.csv"));
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Regex allcaps = new Regex("[A-Z]{1,7}");
    string uneditedtext = text;
    MatchCollection matched = allcaps.Matches(uneditedtext);

    bool found = false;
    while (found == false && !reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var lines = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = lines.Split(',');

        var upperCaseWords = uneditedtext.Split(' ').Where(w => w == w.ToUpper());

        //  string capsrgx = @"([A-Z]{1,7})";
        //  Regex capspresent = new Regex(capsrgx);
        //  Regex allcaps = new Regex("[A-Z]{1,7}");
        //  MatchCollection matched = allcaps.Matches(uneditedtext);
        //  Match m = Regex.Match(text, capsrgx);
        //  Match test = allcaps.Match(uneditedtext);

        dict.Add(values[0], values[1]);

        foreach (Match matches in matched)
        {
            testlist.Add(matches.Value);
            // Console.WriteLine(matches.Value);


            //foreach (string word in uneditedtext.Split(' '))
            //For each key in dictionary
            foreach (var k in dict)
            {
                //If the unedited text contains a key from the dictionary
                if (matches.Value.Contains(k.Key))
                {
                    //replace that string with the key and its corresponding value
                    text = uneditedtext.Replace(k.Key, k.Key.ToString() + "<" + k.Value.ToString() + ">");

                    //When match and replcae found, return true
                    //m = m.NextMatch();

                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    found = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    return text;
}
```

and I get the output:

> AAP AAR< At any rate >

This happens even if I enter in more than one key/value pair. But I want both of these keys to be replaced by their extended versions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you mean that you get the shortest possible match for the regex instead of the longest possible match?

Comment: The matching works fine, it gets all the matches that are all caps. I just can't get my method to iterate over until all the matches in the string are found and replaced, it will only work successfully if there is just 1 abbreviation, if there are more than 1 then it won't work.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then read carefully the information on *"How to debug small programs"* linked at the bottom of the page. It is too much to expect us to read and understand a big lump of code where a some of it works so we have to find the bit that does not work and then debug that part.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need this code:

```
public string TextSpeak(string text)
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(@"H:\SECourseowork\textwords.csv")
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .Aggregate(text, (a, x) => a.Replace(x[0], String.Format("{0}<{1}>", x[0], x[1])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is here:

```
text = uneditedtext.Replace(k.Key, k.Key.ToString() + "<" + k.Value.ToString() + ">");
```

Note that you are replacing text in `uneditedtext`. I.e. you are starting from scratch every time you replace a string, discarding whatever else you had done.

You can *kind of* get your code to work by doing this instead:

```
text = text.Replace(k.Key, k.Key.ToString() + "<" + k.Value.ToString() + ">");
```

I say "kind of", because **a)** this approach begs the question: why are you using regex at all here? why not just iterative call `string.Replace()` using each key/value pair?; and **b)** using `string.Replace()` this way assumes that the value of a key/value pair does not itself contain any of the keys.

The algorithm also seems inefficient in the sense that you are populating the dictionary as you replace strings, which means you reprocess each key/value pair again for every key/value pair that follows it. I would think you'd rather populate the dictionary first from the input file, and only after you have completed read the input file, then start processing the text.

You also seem to not be taking advantage of the fact that you have a dictionary. You are using the dictionary as a simple collection of pairs of values, testing each key in the dictionary against the text you've found. Instead, you should be looking up the found text (which is expected to match a key in the dictionary) in the dictionary, an O(1) operation.

IMHO, better alternatives (assuming first you populate the dictionary before doing any text processing) include:

1. Enumerate the matches in the text. Use the match index and length to identify where in the new text the inserted text should go. Use `StringBuilder` to build the new string as you go, by appending all the text from the end of the previous match, and then appending the inserted text (i.e. `"<" + k.Value.ToString() + ">"`).
2. Instead of using a regex that looks for text meeting the *pattern* of a valid key, just build your regex from the keys themselves. E.g. something like `new Regex(string.Join("|", dict.Keys))`. Then matches are guaranteed to be in your dictionary. Everything else remains the same as in #1, but since you are guaranteed the key is in the dictionary, the implementation is slightly simplified. (It might even be more efficient; whether it is depends on how the regex is implemented).
3. Just use `Regex`'s text replace features. I don't recall the syntax off the top of my head, but you should not need to actually enumerate the matches. `Regex` will let you specify a search and replacement pattern, and optionally allow you a callback to provide the replacement text. Then editing the string is just a single call to `Regex.Replace()`.

If you want more specific advice than that, please provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem.